# Prevent registration between certain hours

Tags: php, if-statement, time, vbulletin

I'm trying to figure a little routine for my forum software (vBulletin 3.x which supports PHP routines via a hook system). I have this code from some research I did before but the conditional isn't functioning as I intended - it will only be 'true' if the start time is set to 0000 or later.

```
$regtime = gmdate('Hi');
$pnr_b1 = "2300";
$pnr_b2 = "0600";

if ($regtime > $pnr_b1 && $regtime < $pnr_b2) {
 // prevent registration code
}
```

Can anyone help? For reference I'm running PHP Version 5.3.29 in case that influences your suggestions.

Comment: Please give more details then "...it doesn't work".

Comment: You're comparing strngs, not times, and there is no string greater than `2300` that is also less than `0600`

Comment: @HoboSapiens Thanks, I was guessing that was the issue, but can't work out how else to do it. Have been trying for a while now with a few suggestions I've found, but not had any luck - hence the plea for help :)

Comment: you should consider using `DateTime` classes instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead comparing strings, you could also use `DateTime` objects so that you could easily compare time:

```
$regtime = new DateTime('23:15');
$from_time = new DateTime('23:00');
$to_time = new DateTime('23:30');

if($regtime >= $from_time && $regtime <= $to_time) {
    echo 'okay, process this';
} else {
    echo 'not allowed';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work. I tried this test: $pnr_b1 to 23:00 and pnr_b2 to 23:15 - I then tried to register at 23:30 (current local time here) and it still blocked me. Any idea why @Ghost

Comment: @SomeGuy yeah the logic is wrong, its suppposed to be the inclusion checking, i revised it check again

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
<?php
$regtime = gmdate('Gi');
$pnr_b1 = 2300;
$pnr_b2 = 600;
if ($regtime > $pnr_b1 or $regtime < $pnr_b2) {
    echo "fail";
}
```

Comment: You should not use `0600`, since that is octal notation and represents a completely different value than `600`. I'm not sure if this may actually lead to a bug, but just don't do it.

Comment: so your suggesting just 600?

Comment: Out of interest, what value would gmdate return for 6am? Also, is the solution here just to have an 'or' instead? I'm not sure that's all it is?

Comment: Yes, `600` and `Gi` instead of `Hi`.

Comment: i also change "2300" to 2300 (no quotes, that would make it a string)

Comment: ok, so you arent saying this wont work, you are saying "this works, just becareful because of the octal notation."

Comment: Again, this *may* have actually led to bugs, I just haven't had enough coffee yet to work out a concrete example. Thanks for fixing it.

Comment: I'll give it a go and keep an eye on this for any different answers in the meantime. While on the topic of down votes, I'm a bit 'miffed' my question got one - tough crowd! :)

Comment: i would suggest saying "The results that are return end up being true" or "I don't know why now isnt less then 2300, instead of "it doesn't work"

Comment: think about the next guy that reads this question, he would want to match his error with the error you are getting.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive feedback @bart2puck - I've gone ahead and tried to tidy up my initial question further. Still a SO newbie I'm afraid!